# Text over image in list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to put a text field inside list and over a image ([like this](http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/2D/E7/ef2988092f8f2de7.png))

I manage to make it right on one list item, but when I add more all of the text fields stuck on the first image ([like this](http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/9E/54/370193726bd69e54.png))

Here is my code :

HTML

```
         <ul class="panel">

        <li>

        <img src="">

            <span class="text-field" class="clearfix">

            <h2>text</h2>

             </span>

        </li> 
          </ul>
```

CSS

```
          .panel li {display: inline-block; padding-right: 10px;}
          .panel li img{width: 100%;}
          .text-field {position: absolute; top: 212px; left: 0; width: 100%; }
          .text-field h2{color: #fff; background-color: #ff481c; display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; padding: 5px 10px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `position: relative` for `.panel li` - For its `absolute` children to consider its top / left as `0, 0`

i.e.

```
.panel li {display: inline-block; padding-right: 10px; position: relative;}
```